# Fuzzy search on a phrase using Hibernate Search

Tags: java, hibernate, lucene, hibernate-search

I am using Hibernate Search to search for titles of tv shows on my web app.

I can use the method `fuzzy()` on `keyword()` in order to perfom fuzzy searches on keywords, but I need to take into account the whole title, so I am using `phrase()` instead of `keyword()`. The method `fuzzy()` is not defined for `phrase()`, so I was wondering if there is an easy way to achieve fuzzy searches on phrases using Hibernate Search.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just need a `PhraseQuery` with slop (that is, extra words thrown in), then you can set the slop on a phrase query like:

```
queryBuilder.phrase()
    .setSlop(2)
    .onField("myField")
    .sentance("this sentence missing something")
    .createQuery();
```

However, I'm not aware of anything in the Hibernate APIs that supports embedding fuzzy queries in phrases, but in Lucene, you can work with the `SpanQuery` API to build that.  [`SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper.html) and [`SpanNearQuery`](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_0_0/core/org/apache/lucene/search/spans/SpanNearQuery.html), in particular, are what you would need.  Something like:

```
FuzzyQuery query1 = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("field", "fuzy"));
FuzzyQuery query2 = new FuzzyQuery(new Term("field", "phrse"));
Query wrappedQuery1 = new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper<FuzzyQuery>(query1);
Query wrappedQuery2 = new SpanMultiTermQueryWrapper<FuzzyQuery>(query2);
SpanQuery[] clauses = {wrappedQuery1, wrappedQuery2};
SpanNearQuery(clauses, 0, true);
```

Comment: Thanks. For the moment I'll stick with the slop method, which I was already using. In the future I will try to implement a spell checker, since I think it would be an overall better solution than a fuzzy search.